# C# Only assign a datetime value if not NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

We have a custom object that i'm trying to assign and populate from a dataset. It works fine unless there is a NULL value in the datetime fields.

here is the object example:

```
public class Test
{

    public DateTime Date1{ get; set; }
    public DateTime Date2{ get; set; }
 }
```

We are wondering how best to byparse assigning any value if the value is null:

```
var convertedList = (from rw in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    select new Test()
       {
          Date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(rw?["StartDate"]),
          Date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(rw?["EndDate"])
        }).ToList();
```

The following throws an exception (as it should) when null. Just wondering the best practice to handle this? Note we cannot use a nullable datetime (datetime?) due to an external app.

Idealy, we would not want to assign the datetime if null

Comment: `Idealy, we would not want to assign the datetime if null` It needs some form of value if it isn't nullable (even if it is just `MinValue` or `MaxValue`). What value do you want it to have?

Comment: we are storing as dates, just not nullable dates. Problem is , the end date will sometimes not have any value assigned in the database.

Comment: Then there is no need to call `Convert.ToDateTime` (if it is already a `DateTime`). Are you able to answer the question in my first comment?

Comment: `we are storing as dates, just not nullable dates.` If it isn't a nullable data in the database, how is `rw?["StartDate"]` returning `null`?

Comment: What are the constraints of the external app? Can it not use the nullable DateTime type, or is it only a problem if the value is null? You could make the property `DateTime?` and implement the `get` to return your choice of default if null.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to Assign some default value like:

```
Date1 = rw?["StartDate"]==null?DateTime.MinValue:Convert.ToDateTime(rw?["StartDate"]);
```

Or just ignore those with null values:

```
var convertedList = (from rw in dt2.AsEnumerable() where rw["StartDate"] != null && rw["EnDate"] != null
    select new Test()
    {
        Date1 = (rw["StartDate"] == null ? Convert.ToDateTime(rw["StartDate"]) : new DateTime()),
        Date2 = (rw["EndDate"] == null ? Convert.ToDateTime(rw["EndDate"]) : new DateTime())
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for NULL and replace with a date you want.

```
var convertedList = (from rw in dt2.AsEnumerable()
    select new Test()
    {
        Date1 = (rw["StartDate"] == null ? Convert.ToDateTime(rw["StartDate"]) : new DateTime()),
        Date2 = (rw["EndDate"] == null ? Convert.ToDateTime(rw["EndDate"]) : new DateTime())
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you not use DateTime.TryParse which will try to convert the string into a dateTime but if it can't it will use dateTime.minValue?

Answer (score -1):

Are you going for sanity checks on inputted values? If so, what I call "Passive Error Reporting" might be the way.

[INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/ee652637(v=vs.95)) is all about telling the user about issues - and allowing you to check of there are no errors before comitting - without "resorting" to Exceptions.

You use it often in WPF where the ViewModel might be required to be accept nullable values or even strings for Numbers (for entirely view reason), but the Model can not accept Null values or anything but parsed Integers.